# Filter state in React without removing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a react component that can filter a list based on value chosen from a drop-down box. Since the `setState` removes all data from the array I can only filter once. How can I filter data and still keep the original state? I want to be able to do more then one search.

Array list:

```
  state = {
tree: [
  {
    id: '1',
    fileType: 'Document',
    files: [
        {
          name: 'test1',
          size: '64kb'
        },
        {
          name: 'test2',
          size: '94kb'
        }
    ]
  }, ..... and so on
```

I have 2 ways that I'm able to filter the component once with:

```
  filterDoc = (selectedType) => {
   //way #1
   this.setState({ tree: this.state.tree.filter(item => item.fileType === selectedType) })

  //way#2
  const myItems = this.state.tree;
  const newArray = myItems.filter(item => item.fileType === selectedType)
  this.setState({
    tree: newArray
  })      
}
```

Search component:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {

  change = (e) => {
    this.props.filterTree(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="col-sm-12" style={style}>
            <input
            className="col-sm-8"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            style={inputs}
            />
            <select
            className="col-sm-4"
            style={inputs}
            onChange={this.change}
            >
                <option value="All">All</option>
              {this.props.docTypes.map((type) =>
                <option
                  value={type.fileType}
                  key={type.fileType}>{type.fileType}
                </option>)}
            </select>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

And some images just to get a visual on the problem.
Before filter:
[image]

After filter, everything that didn't match was removed from the state:

[image]

Comment: `have two property in state one to keep original value and another to keep search results` update the `result` property on search

Comment: @CodeManiac I was thinking about that too, but is that really a good approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not replace original data**

Instead, change what filter is used and do the filtering in the `render()` function.

In the example below, the original data (called `data`) is never changed. Only the filter used is changed.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'one',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'two',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'three',
  },
]

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      filter: null,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const filter = this.state.filter
    const dataToShow = filter
      ? data.filter(d => d.id === filter)
      : data

    return (
      <div>
        {dataToShow.map(d => <span key={d.id}> {d.text}, </span>)}
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({
              filter: 2,
            })
          }
        >
          {' '}
          Filter{' '}
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='root' />
</body>
```

Comment: I would agree the same solution if the filter logic is not complicated.

Comment: If filtering is expensive, then use a [memoized selector](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

Answer (score 2):

Don't mutate local state to reflect the current state of the filter.  That state should reflect the complete available list, which should only change when the list of options changes.  Use your filtered array strictly for the view.  Something like this should be all you need to change what's presented to the user.

```
change = (e) => {
   return this.state.tree.filter(item => item.fileType === e.target.value)
}
```