# React filtering state in a parent component with Producer / Consumer

Tags: reactjs, filter

I have a state held in a file `Body` which is consumed by a direct child `WikiReference` as a Consumer. Values are passed to child Components of `WikiReference` as props. One of these children needs to be able to pass a value back up to body (or somewhere else perhaps) to filter the data set used in `WikiReference`

I think that the comment [displayed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54171002/1249379) is the way forward but I'm having trouble thinking my way round how to implement the filter such that the click is in one component and the filtering is on another.

```
change = (e) => {
   return this.state.tree.filter(item => item.fileType === e.target.value)
}
```

[image]

### Body.js

```
function Body() {
    const [searchState, setSearchState] = useState({
      searchCriteria: "",
      headers:[],
      references: []
    });

  return (

    <>
      <SearchContext.Provider value={{searchState, setSearchState}}>
          <Search />
          <WikiHeader />
          <WikiReference />
      </SearchContext.Provider>

    </>
  );
}

export default Body;
```

### WikiReference.js return section

```
return (
  <>
  {

    references.map(reference => {
      console.log(reference);
      return(
        <div class="container">
          <Title title={reference.title} url={reference.url}/>
          <Domain domain={reference.domain}/>
          <Type type={reference.type}/>
          <IsGov isGov={reference.isGov} onClick={onClick}/>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
  </>
```

);

### Type.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "../../../App.css"

class Type extends Component {

switch(type){
  switch(type) {
    case 'article':
      return  <span><i  className="fa fa-file-text float-right entryicon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      //return 'fa fa-file-text';
    case 'video':
      return  <span><i  className="fa fa-video-camera float-right icon-red entryicon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      //return 'fa fa-video-camera';
    case 'audio':
      return  <span><i  className="fa fa-headphones float-right icon-orange entryicon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    case 'forum':
        return  <span><i  className="fa fa-comments float-right icon-blue entryicon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    default:
      return 'foo';
  }
}

render(){
  return(
    this.switch(this.props.type)
  );

  }

}

export default Type;
```

Comment: Since you are using react context API. You just need to subscribe to the value in the component where you need the data. You don't have to pass the props to parents or in the hierarchy. It's only needed when you don't have state management like redux or context API

Comment: @NobalMohan, can you give an example of this?

Comment: Hope this blog helps https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/

Comment: Not really. It deals with Providers and Consumers which I already have rather than filters. But thank you.